# Avoid copying of data between user and kernel space and vice-versa

Tags: linux, mmap

I am developing a active messaging protocol for parallel computation that replaces TCP/IP. My goal is to decrease the latency of a packet. Since the environment is a LAN, i can replace TCP/IP with simpler protocol to reduce the packet latency. I am not writing any device driver and i am just trying to replace the TCP/IP stack with something simpler. Now I wanted to avoid copying of a packet's data from user space to kernel space and **vice-versa**. I heard of the mmap(). Is it the best way to do this? If yes, it will be nice if you can give links to some examples. I am a linux newbie and i really appreciate your help.. Thank you...

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: If you're a "linux newbie", I would think twice before trying to replace TCP/IP with something "simpler". Even on a LAN, don't assume that you can dispense with features like checksums and retransmissions.

Comment: ya.. but i am learning linux and hope to do this project. your suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use UDP, that is already pretty fast. At least it was fast enough for W32/SQLSlammer to spread through the whole internet.

About your initial question, see the `(vm)splice` and `tee` Linux system calls.

From the manpage:

> The three system calls splice(2),
>   vmsplice(2), and tee(2)), provide
>   userspace programs with full control
>   over an arbitrary kernel buffer,
>   implemented within the kernel using
>   the same type of buffer that is used
>   for a pipe. In overview, these system
>   calls perform the following tasks:
>
> splice(2)
>
> ```
>   moves data from the buffer to an arbitrary file descriptor, or vice
> ```
>
> versa, or from one buffer to another.
>
> tee(2)
>
> ```
>   "copies" the data from one buffer to another.
> ```
>
> vmsplice(2)
>
> ```
>   "copies" data from user space into the buffer.
> ```
>
> Though we talk of copying, actual
>   copies are generally avoided. The
>   kernel does this by implementing a
>   pipe buffer as a set of
>   reference-counted pointers to pages of
>   kernel memory. The kernel creates
>   "copies" of pages in a buffer by
>   creating new pointers (for the output
>   buffer) referring to the pages, and
>   increasing the reference counts for
>   the pages: only pointers are copied,
>   not the pages of the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Actually i need to absolutely reduce the network latency by bypassing the TCP/IP stack. This is my experimentation for my thesis. Basically i need a buffer that is shared between kernel and user space. Do you have any ideas for doing this?? Thanks....

Comment: Are you kidding me? Perhaps you should run some benchmarks. Do you understand the difference between packet based and stream based? You know, speed comes at a compromise, and the speed/latency benefits of UDP are well understood.

Comment: UDP is very good for broadcasting or any other case when loosing some data is fine. Under-the-hood stream based protocols send packets. The question is how acknowledgments/retransmissions are managed.

Comment: I'm upvoting because despite the UDP advice (which may be problematic for some applications), the disucssion of recently invented system calls is quite on target, particularly vmsplice.

Comment: Thank you, finally someone looks into the quintessence of my posting instead of forcing his own protocol preferences over the real topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the environment is a LAN, i can replace TCP/IP with simpler protocol to reduce the packet latency

Generally, even in LAN UDP packets tend to be lost, also they will be lost if client 
do not have enough time to consume it...

SO no, do not replace TCP with something else (UDP). Because if you do need reliable delivery TCP would be the fastest (because everything connected to acknowledgments and retransmission is done in kernel space).

Generally in normal case there is no latency drawbacks using TCP (of course do not forget `TCP_NODELAY` option)

About sharing the memory. Actually all memory you allocate is created with mmap. So the kernel will need to copy it somehow in any case when it creates a packet from driver.

If you are talking about reducing copying it is usually done for files/sockets and 
`sendfile()` used that indeed prevents copying data between kernel and user. But I assume
you do not need to send files.

Comment: UDP packets do *not* tend to get lost in LAN at all. And the receiving buffer of the OS is actually quite large. You should check your facts before downvoting others.

Comment: @ynpos - yes, they are (for experience). Also the fact that buffers are big does not prevent form any kind of server to loose CPU for some reason and buffers may become full. So, yes, UDP packets do not lost frequently but this happens. You can't relay on this.